# Intel, DVMT & Linux: a question

Tags: linux, graphics, ram, intel, gpu

In my Intel notebook BIOS I can change the amount of memory allocated to the integrated GPU (from 32MB to 512MB, via the selector "**Pre-Allocated Memory**").

My question is:

Does Linux change the amount of dedicated video memory **dinamically** or should I set it fixed at max (512MB) for best graphics performance?